# Google charts : customize range selector design

Tags: reactjs, charts, google-visualization, react-google-charts

Is there any way to customize range selector design in google charts. Please see below.

Existing:

[image: existing design]

Required:

[image: Required Design]

Comment: out of the box, you can increase the size of the axis labels using --> `chartOptions.hAxis.textStyle.fontSize` -- in order to change the handles or add the scroll bar, you will need to manually modify the control's SVG on the `'ready'` event...

Comment: had a quick look ... library doesn't seem to provide direct way to modify the styles of the range controls ... however you can simply use css ..